# How to find matched lines with string pattern using variable length

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using Notepad++ and regex, I need to find all lines from a large (3MB) text file with a pattern like this:
"Could not find store with warehouseid: 12 and zipcode 55555"

The number following the warehouseid:  could be 1 or two digits, whereas the number following the zipcode is always a space followed by 5 characters of a zipcode.

I want to select out all the substrings that include "warehouseid: __ and zipcode _____", so I would end up with a list of substrings like this:

"warehouseid: 14 and zipcode 44444"
"warehouseid: 5 and zipcode 44444 "
"warehouseid: 44 and zipcode 44444"
"warehouseid: 44 and zipcode 44444"
"warehouseid: 44 and zipcode 44444"

What Ive started with is this:
^.*(warehouseid:).*$

but now I want to select the next n characters starting with "warehouseid"

Comment: `warehouseid: \d\d? and zipcode \d\d\d\d\d`

Comment: `but now I want to select the next n characters starting with "warehouseid"` give an example of this. `"warehouseid[\S\s]{n}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
Find What:    .*(warehouseid:\h*\d{1,2})\b.*(zipcode\h*\d{5})\b.*|(.+)\R*
Replace With: (?{1}$1 and $2:)
```

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(warehouseid:\h*\d{1,2})`
- `\b` - word boundary to ensure only 1 or 2 digits are captured into Group 1
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(zipcode\h*\d{5})`
- `\b` - word boundary to ensure only 5 digits are captured into Group 2
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `|` - or
- `(.+)\R*` - a whole line that does not meet the criteria.

The `(?{1}$1 and $2:)` replacement pattern replaces with Group 1, `and` and Group 2 values or just removes the whole line that does not match the criteria.

[image]

Comment: Oh this is freakin awesome!  I had never used parameters within the replace field before.  Im going to look that up.  This worked perfectly for what I was doing.

Comment: Just FYI: `(?{1}` checks if Group 1 matched, and if yes, the replacement is `$1 and $2`, else the replacement is an empty string. Also, if you are worried about empty lines between the matching lines, use `.*(warehouseid:\h*\d{1,2})\b.*(zipcode\h*\d{5})\b.*\R*|(.+)\R*` and replace with `(?{1}$1 and $2\n:)`.

Answer (score 0):

This finds the whole line and give you the  "warehouseid: __ and zipcode _____" as a group (selection):

`"Could not find store with (warehouseid: \d{1,2} and zipcode \d{5})"`

Check the explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/b1cVq8/1).

If you want to get the warehouseid "XX" and the zipcode "XXXXX" as groups then use @Wiktor Stribiżew solution.